# How to store TimeStamp? Is there automatic field for CreatedOn

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am new to mongoDB. I have following code create collection and document But there is no timestamp field. Is there any way to insert `created_on` automatically in documents.

```
db.createCollection("countries"); //Created collection
db.countries.insert({"short_name":"AF","country_name":"Afganistan"});  //Created document
db.countries.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d1d5bcb8173a625961ff34"), "short_name" : "AF", "country_name" : "Afganistan" }
```

What I am really after is assigning a default "created_on" to my documents using Cake PHP. So how do you do that?

Comment: MongoDB itself is schema-less. It defines nothing automatically or by default. What programming language or environment are you intending to work in?

Comment: I am working in `cakephp mongo`

Comment: Can you give example how to store created on field in my document?

Comment: If you use mongoose,you can defines default value, like timestamp

Comment: Actuall I am newer so Don't what is `mongoose` but I use shell script for `mongodb`

Comment: Ok,then you can't have default field in mongodb.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mongodb will not insert anything automatically except the '_id' field. You can get the time of insertion from '_id' field like this -

`ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()`

The result would look something like this -

`ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z")`

If you want to insert created_on field yourself then -

1. If you are on mongo shell then new Date() would insert the current time.

   `db.mycollection.insert({ 'created_on' : new Date() })`
2. And if you want to use raw PHP then -

   `$collection->save(array("created_on" => new MongoDate()));`

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
echo (new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("612e10058e19a6074399f7dd"))->getTimestamp();
```